# IdHTTP Access Violation on Disconnect

Tags: delphi, authentication, indy, disconnect, idhttp

Indy 10:

two threads, thread 1 is calling Get on an TIdHTTP and blocked reading data.
thread 2 will call disconnect on the same TIdHTTP in order to interrupt the Get.

I'm using Digest Authentication on the TIdHTTP and i get an AV ocassionally.

callstack for thread 1:

```
40491D [system.pas][System][@ClassDestroy][8989]
69EF2B [..\..\common\IdAuthenticationDigest.pas][IdAuthenticationDigest][TIdDigestAuthentication.Destroy][109]
404567 [system.pas][System][TObject.Free][8313]
6A2B69 [..\..\Common\IdHTTP.pas][IdHTTP][TIdCustomHTTP.DoOnDisconnected][1587]
534574 [IdTCPConnection.pas][IdTCPConnection][TIdTCPConnection.Disconnect][532]
534B3B [IdTCPConnection.pas][IdTCPConnection][TIdTCPConnection.Disconnect][767]
6A3FB3 [..\..\Common\IdHTTP.pas][IdHTTP][TIdCustomHTTP.DoRequest][2101]
```

callstack for thread 2:

```
402BA3 [system.pas][System][@FreeMem][2477]
404521 [system.pas][System][TObject.FreeInstance][8294]
40491D [system.pas][System][@ClassDestroy][8989]
69EF2B [..\..\common\IdAuthenticationDigest.pas][IdAuthenticationDigest]        [TIdDigestAuthentication.Destroy][109]
404567 [system.pas][System][TObject.Free][8313]
6A2B69 [..\..\Common\IdHTTP.pas][IdHTTP][TIdCustomHTTP.DoOnDisconnected][1587]
534574 [IdTCPConnection.pas][IdTCPConnection][TIdTCPConnection.Disconnect][532]
534B3B [IdTCPConnection.pas][IdTCPConnection][TIdTCPConnection.Disconnect][767]
```

basically at the end of the DoRequest it drops into a disconnect.  seems like there's a race condition on the disconnects trying to free Request.Authentication.

downloaded the latest code for Indy 10 and looking at the code i believe the behavior should be the same.

i believe calling disconnect from another thread is the recommended usage pattern, am i wrong?  is this a bug in Indy?  seems like it would be necessary to lock the disconnect but hard to see what deadlocks that might create.  anyone else ran into this?

Comment: you can't use Indy like this. You are supposed to manipulate the object in one thread. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: i'm not sure, see this thread for example, it seems as if this was the expected way to interrupt a get request.  http://www.delphigroups.info/2/4/208119.html

Comment: @whosrdaddy: not true. Indy is designed to support this kind of usage. In fact, some of Indy's own components, like `TIdTelnet`, do exactly the same thing internally that Mike is doing. Unless you use timeouts, disconnecting the socket from another thread is the only way to abort a blocked I/O operation.

Comment: So this must be a locking bug then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, what you are encountering is a race condition with both threads trying to free the same `Request.Authentication` object twice when the socket is being disconnected.  Given the stack traces, both threads would have to be disconnecting the socket at exactly the same time, because `Disconnect()` only calls `DoOnDisconnect()` if the `IOHandler` is still open, and the `IOHandler` is closed before `DoOnDisconnect()` is called.

What you could try doing is use the `OnStatus` event to enter a thread-safe lock such as a critical section or mutex in the `hsDisconnecting` state, and leave the lock in the `hsDisconnected` state.  `IOHandler.Close()` and `DoOnDisconnect()` are called in between those states, so that would effectively serialize your threads so they cannot disconnect the socket and free the `Request.Authentication` object at the exact same time anymore.

Comment: thanks, that is more elegant than what i had in mind.  i'll give it a try under the same stress scenarios but it looks good to me.